# Looking for an early 90s pop song

Tags: identify-this-song, pop

I've been trying to find this song for ages, maybe someone here can help me out. Here is what I know :

- this is a pop (or RnB) song, from around 1991 or 1992. More specifically, it's from a mixtape I found in 1994, but most songs on it were from 91-92
- Other songs that were on this tape : En Vogue (My Lovin), Hi Five (I Like the Way), Shabba Ranks (Mr Lover Man), Bobby Brown (Humpin Around),...
- quite a slow song, around 80-85 bpm I would say
- Male singer. Possibly a boys band
- I remember seeing a video clip for this song at some point. Although this memory is very blurry, I think it had one scene with a lady in a red dress, going down some stairs, with some other characters dressed in black or grey moving around her. It seemed like everything was black and white, except for the lady and her dress

The chorus goes something like this :

Byyyyeeeeee (sang in chorus)

nobody (one voice)

Byyyyeeeeee (sang in chorus)

baby (one voice)

Byyyyyyyyeeeeeeeeee (again in chorus, but longer this time)

Then this pattern is repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems like I was able to find it by coincidence. It was :

R. Kelly (with Public Announcement) - She's Got That Vibe ([video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhifzINUMJM))

Apparently I misheard the lyrics ("bye" instead of "vibe"), which made it more difficult to find. Also the tempo was much faster than I thought...